# "if (fn) fn()" or "fn && fn()"

Tags: javascript

I've seen many times that `fn && fn()` is an optimization of `if (fn) fn()`.

My question are: why? and, what is the generated code for both solutions?

Comment: What do you mean by "generated code"?

Comment: @Kobi I'm guessing he means what the JavaScript in question is compiled to - the low level code.

Comment: @kobi, kba is right, I mean the low level code, assembler.

Comment: JavaScript is an interpreted language so it doesn't necessarily compile to anything. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252081/does-javascript-compile-or-two-pass-interpret

Comment: @juhana http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/138521/is-javascript-interpreted-by-design

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `&&` operator in JavaScript is *short-circuited*, meaning that if the left-hand side is `false`, the right-hand side isn't evaluated at all. That's why `fn && fn()` is safe even if `fn` is falsey (`null`, `undefined`, etc.).

The "code generated" will depend entirely on the JavaScript engine, but I'd expect it to be quite similar in both cases (the `&&` and the `if`).

It's not an "optimization" in the sense of running faster, but rather in the sense of being shorter to write (particularly so if, like me, you *never* leave `{}` off `if` statements). It has the downside of being *slightly* less clear to people who are new to the language, but it's an idiom quickly learned.

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to do `typeof fn === "function"`?

Comment: @Antony: Yes, it would. You see this idiom in places where the code is expecting a function or nothing (for instance, an optional function argument), and people tend to be okay with it if it fails if you give it something, but the thing you give it isn't a function, on the theory that the documentation for the function (for instance) says you can provide a function or nothing, but not a function or (say) string. :-) Also, some host-provided functions on some engines have `typeof` `"object"` (sadly) but are still callable.

Answer (score 2):

So, by `if (fn) fn()`, you want make sure `fn` is existing before executing it. the `if` condition checks a Boolean value or expression, in JavaScript any falsy value could turn to a `false` value in the `if` Boolean checking condition. Falsy values could be:

- false
- null
- undefined
- The empty string ''
- The number 0
- The number NaN (yep, 'Not a Number' is a number, it is a special
  number)

any other value will be a truthy value.

So, if the `fn` is either a `null` or `undefined` value, the `if` checking will protect you from executing a non-function object.

By `fn && fn()`, you are doing the same: in JavaScript, Boolean expression is lazy checked which means if the first part, in an `&&` operation, is falsy then the second part would not be executed. So, with this feature, you could protect your code from executing a non-function object.

`fn && fn()` is not an optimized version of the other one in terms of performance but is a short version in written.

Both code snippets require a precondition: the function `fn` could be either not defined or an actual function object. If in your code, the `fn` has the possibility of being an object of other types, such as a string, you need add type check before executing, such as:

`if (fn instanceof Function) fn()`

Answer (score 0):

In terms of optimization, IMHO, I would say its because its a better way of making it a one line if then, without having to sacrifice braces and compromising readability, but it wouldn't make the code execute any faster